# cert pinning and transitioning isrg-root let's encrypt

Tags: certificate-pinning

I want to verify, if my app is affected by the event announced by let's encrypt https://letsencrypt.org/2019/04/15/transitioning-to-isrg-root.html

I'm using cert pinning in my android app using the pins for

```
    <!--  Let's Encrypt Authority X3  -->
    <pin digest="SHA-256">YLh1dUR9y6Kja30RrAn7JKnbQG/uEtLMkBgFF2Fuihg=</pin>
    <!-- DST Root CA X3 -->
    <pin digest="SHA-256">Vjs8r4z+80wjNcr1YKepWQboSIRi63WsWXhIMN+eWys=</pin>
```

How I can check my app is affected by the transitioning? Any advice for testing the happy and bad case?

Answer (score 0):

Your app might be affected if running in devices with Android M and older.

To check if your app is affected, you can try to connect to https://valid-isrgrootx1.letsencrypt.org/.

Also, [this thread here](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/mobile-client-workarounds-for-isrg-issue/137807) might help as well.